# Kotlin cannot make out that I've already checked whether the item is in the collection

Tags: kotlin, null-check

```
val map = mapOf(
    'a' to 1,
    'b' to 2,
    'c' to 3
)

val c = 'a'
if (c in map) {
    println(map[c] + 1)
}
```

In the simple code stub, Kotlin compiler does not allow me to perform the operation in `println`.
It yells to me with the following warning:

`Operator call corresponds to a dot-qualified call 'map[c].plus(1)' which is not allowed on a nullable receiver 'map[c]'.`

It drives me mad, I don't want to put `!!` to silence it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as Kotlin is concerned, there is no relation between `c in map` being true and `map[c]` not being null. Note that `c in map` is just sugar for `map.contains(c)`, and `map[c]` is just sugar for `map.get(c)`. `get` and `contains` are two separate methods, not related at all.

In the extreme case, who is to say that the `map` can't be modified (by another thread for example) after the `in` check has passed, and the `c` key is now gone?

If you want to use a map's value, then just access it without checking `c in map`. Do the null check the same way as you would for any other method that returns a nullable value. For example, you could assign it to a local `val` first:

```
val value = map[c]
if (value != null) {
    println(value + 1)
}
```

Or use `?.let`:

```
map[c]?.let { println(it + 1) }
```

There are many other ways to do this, depending on what you are doing with the value exactly, but these two are the most general ones I can think of.

Comment: OK, I got your point. Even if we enter the block of the `if` statement, we cannot guarantee that until the `println` statement, there does not happen anything that might change the `map` including the `c`. Thanks.